Is it possible to have persistent dev-tunnel URLs for apps?
I would like the URL for my bot to persist across debug sessions. Every time I hit Local to start debugging though, it looks like it creates a new Dev-Tunnel which is then written to the .env.local file. But dev tunnels can be persisted based on tunnel id. Can this functionality be exposed somehow?

Hit Local debug
Expected - the same URL to be used as last time
Actual - new URL created


Teams Toolkit currently does not support persistent dev tunnel URLs. However, you can configure a persistent dev tunnel URL manually by using the devtunnel CLI. Follow these steps:

Install dev tunnel cli.
Login with your M365 Account using the command devtunnel user login.
Start your local tunnel service by running the command devtunnel host -p 3978 --protocol http --allow-anonymous.
In the env/.env.local file, fill in the values for BOT_DOMAIN and BOT_ENDPOINT with your dev tunnel URL.
BOT_DOMAIN=sample-id-3978.devtunnels.ms
BOT_ENDPOINT=https://sample-id-3978.devtunnels.ms/


Remove "Start local tunnel" task in tasks.json
Press F5 to start again

